# What is the design protocol for this dimmer?

Tags: led

I bought 3 IDENTICAL 2x4 LED troffer lights and wish to use an Eaton 0 to 10 volt dimmer control on the wall plate.

[image: DIAGRAM FROM EATON]

There is no description for *HOW* this system works, circuit design, logic.  That is, open loop control, closed loop with feedback?   I figure it is open loop control and the signal just feeds into a circuit in the LED Driver on each light; that proportionally reduces output from FULL inversely as dimmer slide is increased(higher volts).  If you have any idea or insight, shed some light in this regard.

If open loop can I figure that one of those wires is the 0 to 10 V (AC, right?) signal and the other is what? just a return line, neutral or something?

https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/products/wiring-devices-connectivity/digital-buyers-guide.html?c=wiring-device-buyers-guide&page=E6

Comment: If the troffer LEDs are not designed to be dimmable, you can't !. If it doesn't say so, they aren't!

Comment: You need to run violet/gray *in normal in-wall power cable* such as 14/2 Romex, not hobby wire.  You will need to use electrical tape to re-mark the wires violet and yellow at both ends.  That's because when low voltage wiring is mixed with AC mains wiring, it must be contained within AC mains (Class I) wiring methods.   But yes. You provision AC power normally to the lights and dimmer, then you daisy-chain the 0-10V controls.   0-10V is a *commercial* dimming system, where 99% of installations are in conduit. Works better there. Irresponsible of Home Depot to sell it to homeowners.

Comment: I hear what you are saying but it seems to contradict what I am seeing.   The purple and gray leads on each light are around 20 or 24 gauge wires-- tiny.  They are also not shielded and are only carry nearly zero amp, 10 volt power.   Use 14/2 Romex plus conduit?? hmmm.  I was looking for details for what is happening internally. . . is this open loop or closed loop control with an error signal.  That is why I was asking in the EE forum originally, for insight there.  Not sure how you know the lights were from Home Depot but they were.  Also, they had no 0to 10 volt dimmers!

Comment: @Schreib The reason to use 14/2 Romex is regulatory. When building things into house wiring, you *need to consider fault conditions*.

Comment: Can you get NM-PCS or MC-PCS type cable where you're at, or are you limited to regular /2 or /3 NM for the run from the dimmer to the lamp?

Comment: Class I wiring  is required per 800.133(A). Oh I see you already asked this on https://www.diychatroom.com/threads/0-to-10-volt-commercial-dimmer-in-troffer-led-units.725496/#post-6590755 and got answers.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking how the switch itself works, not how to wire it. That seems to me to be more of an [electronics.se] question than [diy.se]. Maybe if this doesn't get an answer here, we can push it back over? ;)

Comment: apparently not even the manufacturer knows how this simple dimmer works.  I cannot expect others to!  Their response from app engineer, EE:"This is a 0-10V dimmer, the Gray and Purple wires are called the control wires that need to connect to the  LED driver of the light fixture.
 
The control wires only carry a 0-10VDC signal to the LED driver. All the dimming functions take place in the LED driver."